# Voice Turn by Turn navigation on Apple maps

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, mapkit, directions

I am developing an iOS app. It contains a webview. In the webview there is a address link.When user taps that link Apple Maps opens which shows directions from user's current location to the address. Everything is working fine. The problem is that voice navigations are not working. I am using following link:

```
http://maps.apple.com/?saddr=lat0,long0&daddr=lat1,long1
```

Is there any way I can enable voice turn by turn notification on apple maps. iOS version is > 8.0

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I could not find any solution to turn voice directions on Apple Maps so I switched from Apple Maps to Google Maps and made some changes in info.plist file. Voice directions are working fine in Google Maps now. I added following fields in info.plist

```
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>Please allow this app to get your current location</string>
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>googlechromes</string>
    <string>comgooglemaps</string>
</array>
```

and changed apple link to google maps link

```
http://maps.apple.com/?saddr=lat0,long0&daddr=lat1,long1

comgooglemaps://?saddr=lat0,long0&daddr=lat1,long1
```

Thanks!